# Solve algebraically $n \binom{m+n}{m} = (m+1)\binom {m+n}{m+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I can't get very far with this one :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider 
$$
\begin{align}
\text{LHS}
&=\frac{n(m+n)!}{m!(m+n-m)!}\\
&=\frac{n(m+n)!}{m!n!}\\
&=\frac{(m+n)!}{m!(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(m+1)(m+n)!}{(m+1)m!(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(m+1)(m+n)!}{(m+1)!(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(m+1)(m+n)!}{(m+1)!((m+n)-(m+1))!}\\[9pt]
&=\text{RHS}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left.\binom{m+n}m\middle/\binom{m+n}{m+1}\right.
=\left.\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}\middle/\frac{(m+n)!}{(m+1)!(n-1)!}\right.$$

$$=\frac{(m+1)\cdot m! (n-1)!}{m!\cdot n\cdot(n-1)!}$$

Comment: Are you solving from the left or right of the equal sign?

Comment: @user135094, neither. I've tried to find the ratio of the two binomial coefficients, then apply $$\frac ab=\frac cd\iff ad=bc$$

Comment: @user135094: just cancel the numerator and denominator in the last fraction

Answer (score 0):

Using the identity from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/708537)
$$
r\binom{n}{r}=n\binom{n-1}{r-1}\tag{1}
$$
and the basic
$$
\binom{n}{m}=\binom{n}{n-m}\tag{2}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
(m+1)\binom{n+m}{m+1}
&=(n+m)\binom{n+m-1}{m}\tag{3}\\
&=(n+m)\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}\tag{4}\\
&=n\binom{n+m}{n}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(3)$: apply $(1)$
$(4)$: apply $(2)$
$(5)$: apply $(1)$